# cann't connect to snowflake db due to operational error

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://numerify-dev.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=b27b4485-913c-4ce8-bec9-731e0b709b99&databaseName=*********&schemaName=***&warehouse=******&request_guid=dc137072-10af-4507-a84b-b5b5e5757def

connection to snowflake db

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Aside from just posting the error, you should also include some context as to what you're doing and how you're doing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This OS error is normally seen when the below is true:

- The hostname returned from `select SYSTEM$WHITELIST();` are not whitelisted at your end.
- Not using the latest connector.
- The certificate is intercepted by proxy or other network devices.

Could you check the following:

- The connector version being used is the latest.
- Check the whitelisting is in place, to validate follow the following steps:

  1. Install SnowCD in your Windows
  2. Execute SYSTEM$WHITELIST() in your deployment and save the output in a file -whitelist.json
  3. Execute   'snowcd whitelist.json'
  4. If any failures:

  - Please make sure that all the URLS listed in the whitelist.json are whitelisted in the firewall/proxy in your network.,
  - Check the connectivity on the host URLs that failed the test

If the issue is still seen checking the connector logs will help identify the error. If the issue still persists its better to reach out to snowflake support.